# How to save/load (export/import) symbolized variables?

Tags: export, import, save, subscript

I have a large number of variables/functions with subscripts and use definitions with memoization to avoid recomputing them within a kernel session, but I cannot figure out how to export them all for long-term storage. (Ideally human-readable and in a way that also works when running the code from the command line without the Notebook interface).

I have symbolized the subscripted variables so I can use functions that only operate on symbols (in particular Save, Clear). Below is a minimum working example.

Creating and saving the variables as symbols works fine:

---

```
Get["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]

a⎵Subscript⎵1 = 2    
a⎵Subscript⎵test = 3

Names[StringJoin[$Context, "*"]]

Information[a⎵Subscript⎵1, LongForm -> False]
Information[a⎵Subscript⎵test, LongForm -> False]

Information["a⎵Subscript⎵1", 
 LongForm -> False]
Information["a⎵Subscript⎵test", 
 LongForm -> False]

Save[ NotebookDirectory[] <> "test_symbolize_save.m", "`*"]
```

---

[image: symbolized variables with subscripts before saving]

But when I open a new notebook and load the saved file it loads neither the original variables with subscript (only the internal representation) nor the associated values (even though they are contained in the exported file):

---

```
Get["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]

Get[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "test_symbolize_save.m"]]; 

Names[StringJoin[$Context, "*"]]

Information[2, LongForm -> False]
Information[3, LongForm -> False]

Information["a⎵Subscript⎵1", LongForm -> False]
Information["a⎵Subscript⎵test", LongForm -> False]
```

---

[image: symbolized variables with subscripts after loading]

I entered the subscript via "Ctrl+_" for the first ? calls before exporting and after importing.
The RawInputForm of those calls after importing probably points to the underlying issue, as the intended reference to the subscripted variable points to its stored value instead.

Content of the file exported with Save:

---

```
a⎵Subscript⎵1 = 2     
a⎵Subscript⎵test = 3
```

---

(I also tried DumpSave, and while that saved the variable/function name, it did not save the subscripts and associated values.)

My question: How can I easily and consistently create, export, and import variables/functions with subscripts, so the definitions and computed values are fully restored after import?

I don't have to use symbolize (in fact i never did before), but when I tried Save without symbolizing it did not actually export my variables/functions with subscripts.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I would recommend against using `Notation` and just stick to one dimensional symbols. There are so fewer headaches...

Comment: The issue is that the `Notation` rules weren't saved via `Save`. How you get that to work I'm not entirely sure, but try exporting the `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, and `FormatValues` explicitly. That will work at minimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just save global variables and [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript):

```
Save[file, {"`*", "Subscript"}]
```

If you really want to use the `Notation` package, then the problem is that the functions that know how to convert back and forth between the symbolized and unsymbolized forms are not being saved. Here are your definitions:

```
Get["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_","_"]]]

Subscript[a, 1] = 2
Subscript[a, test] = 3
```

> 2
>
> 3

Here is how to save the needed symbols from the notation package:

```
Block[{NotationBoxTag, Notation`Private`createSymbolizeSingleInstance, 
       MakeExpression, $ContextPath},
SetAttributes[{$ContextPath},Protected];
    Save[
        FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test_symbolize_save.m"}],
        {"`*", NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression}
    ]
]
```

*(The above [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) is not strictly necessary, but there is no need to save all of the definitions when you are going to reload the `Notation` package anyway)*

Then quit the kernel, and reload:

```
Get["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_","_"]]]

Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test_symbolize_save.m"}]];

Subscript[a, 1]
Subscript[a, test]
```

> 2
>
> 3

Here are the contents of the saved file:

```
Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test_symbolize_save.m"}], "String"]
```

> ```
> a⎵Subscript⎵1 = 2  
> a⎵Subscript⎵test = 3
> Attributes[Notation`NotationMakeBoxes] = {HoldAllComplete}
>
> Notation`NotationMakeBoxes[HoldPattern[Notation`ParsedBoxWrapper][
>       Notation`Private`boxes__], Notation`Private`anyForm_] := 
>     TemplateBox[{Notation`Private`boxes}, "NotationTemplateTag"]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeBoxes[a⎵Subscript⎵1, 
>       StandardForm] /; MemberQ[$ContextPath, "Global`"] := 
>     SubscriptBox["a", "1"]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeBoxes[a⎵Subscript⎵test, 
>       StandardForm] /; MemberQ[$ContextPath, "Global`"] := 
>     SubscriptBox["a", "test"]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeBoxes /: Notation`NotationMakeBoxes::usage = 
>      "NotationMakeBoxes is a private version of MakeBoxes."
>
> Notation`NotationMakeExpression[TagBox[Notation`Private`boxes_, 
>       Notation`NotationBoxTag, Notation`Private`opts___], 
>      Notation`Private`anyForm_] := HoldComplete[Notation`ParsedBoxWrapper[
>       Notation`Private`boxes]]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeExpression[TagBox[Notation`Private`boxes_, 
>       "NotationTemplateTag", Notation`Private`opts___], 
>      Notation`Private`anyForm_] := HoldComplete[Notation`ParsedBoxWrapper[
>       Notation`Private`boxes]]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeExpression[SubscriptBox["a", "1"], StandardForm] /; 
>      MemberQ[$ContextPath, "Global`"] := HoldComplete[
>      a⎵Subscript⎵1]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeExpression[SubscriptBox["a", "test"], StandardForm] /; 
>      MemberQ[$ContextPath, "Global`"] := HoldComplete[
>      a⎵Subscript⎵test]
>
> Notation`NotationMakeExpression[Notation`Private`matchedBoxes:
>        SubscriptBox[_, _], StandardForm] /; MemberQ[$ContextPath, 
>       "Global`"] := (Notation`Private`createSymbolizeSingleInstance[
>       Notation`Private`matchedBoxes, "Global`"]; 
>      MakeExpression[Notation`Private`matchedBoxes, StandardForm])
>
> Notation`NotationMakeExpression /: Notation`NotationMakeExpression::usage = 
>      "NotationMakeExpression is a private version of MakeExpression."
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to use `DumpSave` instead of `Save`? I tried ``Block[{NotationBoxTag, Notation`Private`createSymbolizeSingleInstance, 
  MakeExpression, $ContextPath}, SetAttributes[{$ContextPath}, Protected];
 DumpSave[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test_symbolize_save.mx"}], {"Global`", 
   NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression}]]`` but it causes `Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .` warning, which I don't quite understand. Tested in _v11.2_. BTW, _v9_ spits out `ToExpression::esntx` warning in addition.

Comment: @xzczd If you want to use DumpSave, then there is no need to make the file readable. So, don't use Block, and it should work.

Comment: just for clarity, when you say to remove Block, that includes the first argument of it I presume (what is under culry brackets)? If I do that, I get an error message of the form:List::cxt: Invalid context specified at position 1 in {`*,NotationMakeBoxes,NotationMakeExpression}. A context must consist of valid symbol names separated by and ending with `.