# DumpSave and Notation package

Tags: contexts, custom-notation, notation, dumpsave

I tried to follow the answer in [How to save/load (export/import) symbolized variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184954/how-to-save-load-export-import-symbolized-variables). In my case, I would add the code:

```
 DumpSave[ "~/file.mx",{"`*", NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression} ]
```

where it was recommended to not use Block for a DumpSave. This does not work as I get the following error message:

[image]

If I try instead:

```
DumpSave["~/file.mx",{Evaluate[Context[]], NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression} ]
```

then I get:

[image]

although this IS a context and in fact works, if it is the only argument as in:

```
 DumpSave["~/file.mx",Evaluate[Context[]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that `DumpSave` has attribute `HoldRest` which prevents evaluation of all but its first argument.

The documentation of `Evaluate` states:

> - You can use `Evaluate` to override `HoldFirst` etc. attributes of built-in
>     functions.
> - `Evaluate` only overrides `HoldFirst` etc. attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held.

But in

```
DumpSave["~/file.mx",{Evaluate[Context[]], NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression} ]
```

`Evaluate` does not wrap the second argument so it is held unevaluated. Yes, `Evaluated` *does* appear in the second argument, but not at its top level (level 0, a.k.a. *head* of the expression).

Try to use

```
DumpSave["~/file.mx", Evaluate@{Context[], NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression}]
```

or

```
With[{context = Context[]},
 DumpSave["~/file.mx", {context, NotationMakeBoxes, NotationMakeExpression}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both methods work. Just for clarity, I can understand why the second proposition works, but why does the first work, compared to trying to use Evaluate only on Context?

Comment: Your Evaluate was on the second level of the second argument and the `HoldRest` attribute of `DumpSave` prevented scanning of the second level. Try also `SetAttributes[f, HoldRest];f[1, {Evaluate@Context[]}]` vs.`SetAttributes[f, HoldRest];f[1, Evaluate@{Context[]}]`.

Comment: You have assumed @Patrick.B knows how `Evaluate` works. And without reading its documentation your explanation may be vague. (sorry for being picky but another question was posted that assured me that it is the case)

Comment: @Kuba  Yes, I've seen that other question. I added some more (pun allert!) _context_.

Comment: Thanks for the patience you are showing to me. I indeed am not aware on the internal mechanism of Evaluate (or just about any built-in functions to be frank). The explanation and examples ended being clear to me in the end though. Thanks again for putting up with me.

Comment: You're welcome!