Evaluating the RHS of SetDelayed function definition but then deviding it by 2 gives unexpected result!
The following code gives expected result
expr1 = x;
f[x_] := Evaluate[Sin[x] expr1/2]
f[y]

Output:
1/2 y Sin[y]

But if I do the following
expr1 = x;
f[x_] := Evaluate[Sin[x] expr1]/2
f[y]

Output:
1/2 x Sin[y]

I was expecting mathematica to give the same result as before. What is going on here?

Evaluate only causes evaluation if it's wrapping the entire right side

See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190773/1871 (Essentially the same problem. )
